# unfolded table cannot be fully shown when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I use react to make a function that on the page, users can select a group, and when a group is selected(in area G), its members can right away show in the 'users of the group'(in area U). My problem is that with this layout, when unfolding the table in area G, the table 
cannot be fully shown even with a scrollbar scrolling to the bottom.

[image]
[image]

the render part is

```
<div className ={'outermost-container'} style={overflowY:'auto',display:'flex',flexWrap:'wrap',justifyContent:'space-around',}>
    {/*for Area G, */}
    <div>selectableTable</div>
    {/*for area U*/}
    <div style={display:'flex',justifyContent:'space-around'}>
        {/*for left table of area U*/}
        <div>selectableTable</div>
        {/*for buttons in the middle of area U*/}
        <div style={display:'flex' flexDirection:"column"}>2 buttons</div>
        {/*for right table of area U*/}
        <div>selectableTable</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

this is implemented with https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list

With this layout, **are there any ways to show the complete table when scrolling down to bottom when unfolding?** Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the list on the left side out of a flexbox, and use percent to indicate size.